# How do I fix my leaking gutter?

Tags: gutters, downspout

When it rains, my gutter leaks badly.

What's the best way to go about fixing this?

Here's a photo:

[image: leaking gutter]

Comment: what is the photo supposed to show? ... it is very unclear

Comment: Are you sure it's leaking? Looks like it's overflowing. If all that water is from leaks, you need new gutters. It might be blocked with leaves and debris. Please provide a little more clarity on what's going on with it.

Comment: Yeah, it might be clogged with leaves and debris - when I get a chance I'll go up and try and spray things to clean out any clogs.

Comment: A picture from below (taken when it's not raining and the gutter is dry) would give a better indication of the gutter's physical condition, for example, showing rust holes if there were any.

Comment: Our gutters were overflowing when the downspouts got clogged - don't forget to check your downspouts, maybe by running a hose directly into the top of each one and seeing if it drains.

Comment: Our gutters overflowed rearwards, only when the rain was extreme. It turned out that the weight of the water tilted the soffits in, towards the building. You try figuring that one out from even 20 photos, or even climbing up to have a look. ;)) It took several years & several professionals before one finally worked it out.

Comment: To me it looks like it's leaking from behind the gutters.  Are the gutters securely fastened to the fascia? If pulled away, water could be rolling off behind them

Answer (score 2):

Your gutters are overflowing. Get them cleaned along with the downspout.

All of that excess water could have caused them to go out of alignment so you should check for proper slope as well.

If there are trees within 50 feet of your roof then you should get them cleaned yearly; preferably after the leaves have fallen.